# Boostrap 4 div expanding after form submission

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

Wondering if anyone can help... i have this weird issue where my Div is expanding once the form has been Submitted.

After submission i have made an alert if the submission was successful. This alert works but when i click "OK" and go back to the web page, the divs have expanded massively.

I have googled this but cant seem to find any scenarios where people have seen this.

CSS:

```
/* sm */
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  #formDiv {
    width: 20%;
  }
}


/* md */
@media (min-width: 992px) {
  #formDiv {
    width: 20%;
  }
}


/* lg */
@media (min-width: 1200px) {
  #formDiv {
    width: 20%;
  }
}

body {
  /*font-family: 'Shrikhand', cursive;*/
  font-family: 'Rancho', cursive;
  /*font-family: 'Tangerine', cursive; Snelsmore House, Oxford Rd, Donnington, Newbury RG14 3AL*/
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #D4CFBD;
}

.jumbotron {
  /*font-family: 'Rancho', cursive;*/
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
}

.container-fluid {
  min-height: 100%;
}

#mainContainer {
  padding-top: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  background: #D4CFBD;
}

#mainDiv {
  text-align: center;
  background: #D4CFBD;
  height: 50%;
}

#MillyPic,
#stefnCraigPic {
  height: auto;
  max-width: 100%;
}

#formDiv {
  padding-top: 30px;
  margin: auto;
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="container-fluid" id="mainContainer">
    <div id="mainDiv">
        <h2>Hey there,</h2>
        <h2>We would like to invite you to our wedding on the 22nd Dec 2018!</h2>
        <br>
        <h3>To confirm your attendance can you please fill in the below form...</h3>
    </div>
    <hr>
    <div id="formDiv">
      <div id="RSVP">
          <form method="post" class="justify-content-center text-center" >
              <div class="form-check text-left" id="RadioYes">
                  <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="responseRadio" id="Yes" value="1" onclick="dynInput();">
                  <label class="form-check-label" for="Yes">
                      <h4>Attending</h4>
                  </label>
              </div>
              <div class="form-check text-left" id="RadioNo">
                  <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="responseRadio" id="No" value="0" checked>
                  <label class="form-check-label" for="No">
                      <h4>Cant Make it</h4>
                  </label>
              </div>
              <hr id="attendanceHr" class="d-none">
              <div class='d-none form-group' id='guestNamesDivs'>
                  <div class="form-group text-left">
                      <label for="guestName1"><h4>Guest One:</h4></label>
                      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="guestName1" name="guestName1" placeholder="Firstname and Surname">
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group text-left">
                      <label for="guestName2"><h4>Guest Two:</h4></label>
                      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="guestName2" name="guestName2" placeholder="Firstname and Surname">
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group form-check text-left">
                        <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" id="dietaryReq" name="DRYN" onclick="dietaryReqDisplay();">
                      <label class="form-check-label lead" for="dietaryReq">Dietary Requirements.</label>
                  </div>
              </div>
              <div class="d-none" id="dietaryReqTextDiv">
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <textarea class="form-control" id="dietaryReqTextArea" name="DR" rows="3"></textarea>
                  </div>
              </div>
              <br>
              <button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
          </form>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

PHP - TEST alert if form submission successfully goes to Database:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){    
    $attending = $_POST['responseRadio'];

    if($attending == "1"){
        $guest_one = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['guestName1']);
        $guest_two = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['guestName2']);
        $dietary_req = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['DRYN']);
        $dietary_needs = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['DR']); 

        if($_POST['DRYN']=="on"){
            $dietary_req = "1";
            $dietary_req = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$dietary_req);
        }else{
            $dietary_req = "0";
            $dietary_req = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$dietary_req);
        }

        $sql = "INSERT INTO weddingRSVP (guest_1, guest_2, attending, dietary_req, dietary_info) VALUES ('$guest_one', '$guest_two', '$attending', '$dietary_req','$dietary_needs');";        

        if(mysqli_query($conn, $sql)){
            $message .= "You have successful RSVP'd to the wedding. \n As you are attending please go ahead and make a song choice for the reception :)!";
            echo "<script type='text/javascript'>
                    alert('test')
                  </script>";
        } else{ 
            $error .=  "ERROR: Could not able to execute $sql. " . mysqli_error($link);
        }

    }else{        

        $sql = "INSERT INTO weddingRSVP (guest_1, guest_2, attending, dietary_req, dietary_info) VALUES ('$guest_one', '$guest_two', '$attending', '$dietary_req','$dietary_needs');";        

        if(mysqli_query($conn, $sql)){
            $message .= "You have successful RSVP'd to the wedding. \n As you are attending please go ahead and make a song choice for the reception :)!";
        } else{ 
            $error .= "ERROR: Could not able to execute $sql. " . mysqli_error($link);
        }
    }
}
```

If anyone has any ideas on why this is happening i would be really grateful.

EDIT - ADDING JAVASCRIPT:

```
var radioYes = document.getElementById("Yes");
var DivRadioNo = document.getElementById("RadioNo");
var dietaryReq = document.getElementById("dietaryReq");

function dynInput () {
    if (radioYes.checked) {
      document.getElementById("guestNamesDivs").classList.remove("d- 
      none");
      DivRadioNo.classList.add("d-none");
      document.getElementById("attendanceHr").classList.remove("d- 
      none");
    }
}

function dietaryReqDisplay () {
    if (dietaryReq.checked) {
     document.getElementById("dietaryReqTextDiv").classList.remove("d- 
     none");
    }
}
```

[Before Submission](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2eECE.png)

[after submission (1)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k1Ar3.png)

[after submission (3)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kywld.png)

Comment: I don't see any JavaScript.

Comment: echo "<script type='text/javascript'>
                    alert('test')
                  </script>";

This is the only part of the Javascript that runs when the submit is clicked.

Comment: Added the rest of the Javascript, Sorry

Comment: Can you add everything to online editor to replicate the issue?